# How to Use command in Envoirment Variable Ansible Playbook

Tags: ansible, centos, environment-variables

I am trying to use `hostname -f` command in variable with ansible-playbook. After I set the variable, I will use it in `sed` command. When manually execute the commands it works but with Ansible, variable does not work.
When I `echo $hostn` output is empty.

```yaml
---

- hosts: test
  become: true
  become_user: root
  tasks:
        - name: test
          shell: "{{ item }}"
          with_items:
              - hostn=`hostname -f`     <<<<<< not working
              - echo $hostn             <<<<<< not working
              - sed -i "s/test/$hostn/g" /file  <<<< manually works
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Each and every command Ansible runs is a separate SSH command, so a variable you register "on the shell" won't be there the next time. Don't take my words for granted though, run your playbook with `-vvvv` and you'll see what happens behind the scene

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I changed  from sed -i "s/test/$hostn/g" /file to sed -i "s/test/`hostname -f`/g" /file it worked

Answer (score 0):

My advise would be that you should not try to fit all your commands in Ansible `shell` this way, but rather translate them into the corresponding Ansible modules.

What you are looking to achieve can be done with the [`replace`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html) module — in place of `sed` — and the [Ansible fact `ansible_hostname`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#ansible-facts) — in place of `hostname -f`.

This would be the equivalent playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: test
  become: true
  become_user: root

  tasks:
    - replace:
        path: /file
        regexp: test
        replace: "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
```

Comment: yes I know, I am not fan of using shell in ansible, but I am more used to it shell commands, I need to break this habbit. I will try and let you know.